# Loader for CSS / SASS in Webpack

Tags: sass, webpack

I picked up an example webpack config file that has the following loader.

```
   test: /\.scss|.css$/,

   loader: ExtractTextPlugin.extract('style', 'css?sourceMap!postcss')
```

It seems to be working but what I can't understand is that many places it states that you must use a sass-loader but I don't have it installed, and it's not listed inside my packages file.

From what I can see, it's loading the style-loader and then the css loader.

What is happening here? I see no reference to sass /scss only on the test line (above). Also I notice that it is using the extract function off of the ExtractTextPlugin, what is the difference to just using

```
  loader: ['style', 'css?sourceMap!postcss']
```

### Edit

These are the postcss plugins I am using.

```
  require('postcss-import')({addDependencyTo: bundler}),
        require('postcss-inline-comment')(),
        require('postcss-hexrgba'),
        require('postcss-size'),
        require('precss')(),
        require('css-mqpacker')(),
        require('autoprefixer')({
            browsers: ['last 2 version']
        })
```

Comment: Which postcss plugins are you using?

Comment: Hi @bebraw, thanks for the prompt reply. I have updated the question to include the plugins I am using.

Comment: I am just a little confused, because as far as I know I am not using any sass loader but it works! So the next question would be should I be using a sass-loader instead of what ever is making it magically work ?

Comment: I think it's that precss plugin. See https://github.com/jonathantneal/precss .

Comment: Yes, it appears it was, can you add an answer so i can mark you as correct

Comment: I am getting error bundler is not defined

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It works because you have [precss](https://www.npmjs.com/package/precss) postcss plugin enabled. It provides SASS style markup.

Comment: Yep. It was, i decided to remove it and go with the real sass-loader. thanks